Prove that two matrices obtained from the longest element of the weyl group are equal
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra with types $A,D,E$ and $W$ be the corresponding weyl group.
Assume that $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ be the simple roots and $\omega_1,\cdots,\omega_n$ be the fundamental weights of $\mathfrak{g}$.
Let $s_i(1\le i\le n)$ be the simple reflections and $w_0$ be the longest element of $W$.
Then it induces the Nakayama permuattion
$\nu:I\to I$ defined via the equality
$$w_0(\alpha_i)=-\alpha_{\nu(i)}.$$
Here is my question:
We let $t_i(1\le i\le n)$ be the matrix of the simple reflection $s_i\in W$ with respect to the basis of fundamental weights.
For example, if we choose $A_3$ and $i=1$, we have $s_1(\omega_1)=-\omega_1+\omega_2$, $s_1(\omega_2)=\omega_2$, and $s_1(\omega_1)=\omega_3$.
So we have $t_1=\left( \begin{matrix}
 -1&  0&  0\\
 1&  1&  0\\
 0&  0&  1\\
\end{matrix} \right).$
We assume $w_0=s_{i_1}s_{i_2}\cdots s_{i_r}$ be the reduced decomposition of $w_0\in W$ and consider the matirx $M_1=t_{i_1}t_{i_2}\cdots t_{i_r}$.
Since $\nu$ is the Nakayama permutation on $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, then we can get the permutation matrix $M_2$.
I want to know how to prove $M_1=M_2$.
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

This is just a calculation to perform I'm afraid. The permutation you refer to is defined by this so it isn't really a case of checking that they match.
